# Possible to access variable $x in some satisfies expression? XPATH 2 3

Tags: xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0, distinct-values

I created a variable to store the extensions of entities which I can use to build `NOTATION` statements:

```
<xsl:variable name="notations">
              <xsl:for-each select="//@infoEntityIdent">
                <xsl:variable name="uri" as="xs:anyURI" select="unparsed-entity-uri(.)"/>
              <xsl:analyze-string select="$uri" regex="([^.]*$)">
                <xsl:matching-substring>
                  <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/>
                </xsl:matching-substring>
              </xsl:analyze-string>
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
              </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

I wanted to try the `some/satisfies` expression, but the `$x` is out of scope in the `<xsl:text>`

```
    <xsl:if test="some $x in $notations satisfies matches($x,'svg', 'i')">
          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" expand-text="1">&lt;!NOTATION {$x} SYSTEM "SVG"&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="some $x in $notations satisfies matches($x,'jpg', 'i')">
          <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" expand-text="1">&lt;!NOTATION {$x} SYSTEM "JPG"&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
```

If I can't access the `$x` then I'll have to hard-code 'SVG' and use `upper-case()` on the entity to ensure the cases match.

```
<xsl:if test="some $x in $notations satisfies matches($x,'svg', 'i')">
              <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes>&lt;!NOTATION SVG SYSTEM "SVG"&gt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:if>
```

Otherwise, I'm using a loop with `distinct-values()` and `tokenize()`.

```
<xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(tokenize($notations))">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="matches(.,'svg', 'i')">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" expand-text="1">&lt;!NOTATION {.} SYSTEM "SVG"&gt;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="matches(.,'JPG','i')">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes" expand-text="1">&lt;!NOTATION {.} SYSTEM "image/jpeg"&gt;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: I think for your initial variable it would be easier to make it a sequence of strings with e.g. `<xsl:variable name="notations" select="//@infoEntityIdent ! unparsed-entity-uri(.) ! replace(., '.*?([^.]+)$', '$1')"/>`.  But your attempt to be able to use the variable of `some` inside of the `xsl:if` is not going to work, you can of course use the `xsl:for-each`, as you have shown, with my suggestion in the previous sentence, withou the need to call `tokenize`, as there is already a sequence of strings.

Comment: What is the `!` in the select statement?

Comment: It is the XPath 3 simple map operator https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-map-operator, easier to use than `for $s in //@infoEntityIdent return replace(unparsed-entity-uri($s)., '.*?([^.]+)$', '$1')` and better suited to process sequences of atomic values than `/` which is for nodes.